# Django IntegrityError null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to save a form where I take user inputs. I am getting Integrity error. Can anyone please help me out here? I see that people have used request.user.username but I don't see how to use this in my forms. Please don't mind the code as I am still trying to figure out things in Django.

Below are my files:

```
models.py

class CommonModel(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
    requirements = JSONField(default = {})
    specs = JSONField(default= {})
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       abstract = True

    def update(self):
        self.updated_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Item(CommonModel):

    HW = 'HW'
    NW = 'NW'
    SW = 'SW'
    VM = 'VM'
    WI = 'WI'
    SI = 'SI'
    ITEM_TYPES = (
        (HW, 'Hardware'),
        (NW, 'Network'),
        (SW, 'Software'),
        (VM, 'Virtual Machine'),
        (WI, 'Work Item'),
        (SI, 'Support Item'), 
    )

    UNIT_LOE = 'LOE'
    UNIT_USD = 'USD'
    UNIT_TYPES = (
        (UNIT_LOE, 'LOE,MD'),
        (UNIT_USD, 'USD'),
    )

    item_type = models.CharField(default='HW', max_length=5, choices=ITEM_TYPES)
    unit_type = models.CharField(default='USD', max_length=5, choices=UNIT_TYPES)
    otc_price = models.DecimalField(default='0.0', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    annual_price = models.DecimalField(default='0.0', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    gp_code = models.TextField(default='Unknown')
    class Meta:
       abstract = True

class ItemTemplate(Item):
    pass
   # Need ID here to relate to estimate

class ItemObject(Item):
    pass
```

Here is my admin.py

```
class CommonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField:{ 'widget':JSONEditor },
    }

    def otc_price(self,obj):       
        return json_prettified(obj.otc_price)
    def annual_price(self,obj):       
        return json_prettified(obj.annual_price)

from reversion.admin import VersionAdmin

@admin.register(ItemTemplate)
class ItemTemplateAdmin(VersionAdmin):
     list_display = ('title', 'item_type', 'unit_type', 'otc_price','annual_price')
     formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField:{ 'widget':JSONEditor },
     }

@admin.register(ItemObject)
class ItemObjectAdmin(VersionAdmin):
     list_display = ('title', 'item_type', 'unit_type', 'otc_price','annual_price')
     formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField:{ 'widget':JSONEditor },
     }
```

And finally the views.py.

```
def order_create(request):
        cart = ItemObject.objects.all()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ItemObjectCreateForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                for item in cart:
                    annual_price = 122
                    otc_price=100
                    # Logic to calculate the price and put it in estimate table
                    ItemObject.objects.create(
                                             requirements=item.requirements,
                                             specs=item.specs,
                                             annual_price = annual_price,

                    )
                # clear the cart
                #cart.clear()
                order_created()
                # redirect to the payment
                return redirect('success.html')

        else:
            form = ItemObjectCreateForm()
        return render(request,
                      'index.html',
                      {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Here I am trying to store data to ItemObject but while submitting the form, I am getting error.

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains
```

Also my forms.py is like below

```
class ItemObjectCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemObject
        fields = ['title','requirements', 'gp_code', 'specs','author', 'item_type', 'unit_type','comments', 'id'
                  ]
```

Attaching DB 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While form save, [set commit argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to false to prevent the object being saved immediately,

```
item = form.save(commit=False)
item.author = request.user
item.save()
```

And modify

```
ItemObject.objects.create( author=request.user, requirements=item.requirements, specs=item.specs, annual_price = annual_price, )
```

Comment: modify to ItemObject.objects.create( author=request.user, requirements=item.requirements, specs=item.specs, annual_price = annual_price, ) and try

Comment: Its the same result unfortunately. I put author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default='Heena') but that's wrong I guess since its expecting a key. Actually I am able to save the data to the DB its just that it destroys the integrity constraint.

Comment: author is not nullable, so you need to set it before you save the model. In your code you are saving it at two places without setting it. 1) form save 2) ItemObject create.

Comment: How do I set it? That's what my challenge is

Comment: have you tried my answer .. setting at both places before save

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160404/discussion-between-heenashree-khandelwal-and-saji-xavier).

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of `CommonModel` you've required that `author` not be null. Is that correct? Must every instance of `CommonModel` have an `author`? If not, you can alter the definition to allow null values:

```
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Author cannot be null. Even though I am getting same error